# How to get the computed column to find a min value for a given field?

Tags: ms-access

I have a MS Access DataBase with a table as shown below

```
Col A    Col B  Computed Col
Apple    10      10
Apple    20      10 
Apple    15      10 
Orange   10      5
Orange   5       5 
Orange   23      5
Orange   25      5
Grapes   40      30
Grapes   45      30
Grapes   30      30
```

I want to have a computed col i the query to find the min value for the fruit
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The min() function isn't supported in calculated fields in Access. I would just query for it as

```
   SELECT fruits.fruitname ,min(numfruit) as minimum
 FROM fruits GROUP BY Fruitname
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the Min() function around the computed Col section. http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/min.php

Comment: The computed col should be the result, basically min of apples is 10, min of orange is 5 and min of grapes is 30